# Python Script over network

Tags: python, excel, csv, networking

i have a python script that works in my pc and of course my LAN.
It pick up an excel file, put in into a tk treeview and write a .csv file of data are selected in treeview and a streaming software than pick up this file to a livescore graphic.

Is it possible do that workflow by remote computer? So a computer in a remote network can run the application from his hard drive, load the excel but write the csv file on my pc. What i need to do?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) module that allows you to run `ssh` and `scp` commands through a Python script. If the host computer can run Python, you can also run the script there and fetch the results afterwards.

Comment: Interesting... so the workflow is made because on remote computer there will be a newbie person that has only to open the application (that i made from py to exe), load the excel file that i made from my 'server' computer and update it, while update the treeview it will update the .csv file but that i need to access this file from my 'server' pc. I hope that i explained it well as you can understand the situation

Comment: What you can do is write some code to send the data using a [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) object through a socket. On the server you open a socket that waits for a connection from the remote, the remote sends its pickled object, the server reads it and converts it into a csv